# XMLhttprequest not posting (new to it)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send data from javascript to a php page using xmlhttprequests.
It is just like sending form data, eventhough I have copied the examples exactly, it doesnt work.

I know the problem lays with the xmlhttprequest since I have tried sending the same data using an html form with POST and that works fine. So the PHP works.

the errors I get using my code are:

- POST http://localhost/thissite/post 404 (Not Found)
- Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

The current file structure I am using equals:
index.php and store.php in the root and than a folder called js with init.js

```
function sendData() {
    var xmlhttp,
        url = "http://localhost/thissite/store.php";

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for modern browsers
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {
        // code for old IE browsers
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("post", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("sitetarget=/thissite/&buttontarget=firstbutton&amount=2");
}
```

This function is in my init.js file which is linked on my index.php page.

I have tried changing the used URL to:

- store.php
- /store.php
- ./store.php
- ../store.php
- http://localhost/store.php

But I think the URL I use should be correct since that is the url I get send to when I post the form. It is also the same as multiple examples I found in questions posted on here and those users didn't have the same errors as me. This is probably me misunderstanding but I am eager to find out what the problem is with my code before I throw my computer out of the window or pull my last hair out.

Thank you for answering if you do!

Comment: there is nothing in the code you provided that matches the errors you gave. you need to provide the correct code. use the console and look at the line numbers and post the code at those line numbers.

Comment: i have no way of knowing what code is at line 40 of init.js, which is why i askedd you to post the relevant code.

Comment: the code at line 40 is the var xmlhttp thats why I only posted that part cause all the other lines in the file are commented out

Comment: I also added the onstatechange console.log and the response is empty

Comment: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` tells me that that code is inline, in a `<script>` tag on a php page. I'll bet the unexpected `<` is the begining of a php error. use ctrl-u to view the source code and see what is on line 40 of the source code.

Comment: I think the errors came from old code. I use MAMP to host locally, but the updating of the page doesn't happen consistently. I also put the php code on the index.php, since the function I made has to run on the open page and won't run when you post it to an unloaded page. Thx for your help! I am seriously happy you spend some time of your day to help me, you are awesome man.